# What is the author referring to with "UX mail lists"?

Tags: design-patterns, terminology

After reading a [Boxes and Arrows article by Stephen Turbek](http://www.boxesandarrows.com/view/are-design-patterns) (packed with UXy goodness) I am unfamiliar with the phrase "UX mail lists" in context. Is the author actually suggesting a pattern library needs to have a "mail(ing) list"? Is this some meta-pattern of for pattern library maintenance?

> "A code library beats a pattern library [...] It should have the most
>   commonly needed components with brief descriptions and links to
>   example implementations, bug tracking and feature requests, supported
>   by an active development and UX mail lists."

//Edited to make sure you don't think I want to discuss the topic...

Comment: I dont think this is an appropriate question for here,maybe Meta ?

Comment: I inferred he meant an internal mailing list whose charter is discussing UX.

Comment: Is it common create mailing lists instead of just use email group list in whatever app you use in corporate now? The list may not be more than, what, 10 people who would be participating on a group's code repository and UX patern library?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the author in this instance is saying that the UX mail list is there to support the development of a code library. Active discussion will need to occur around a code library of design patterns, with the community discussing UX considerations as well as the quality of the code and suitability to solve design challenges.

Comment: Doesn't "active development" assume community communication? The answer appeared so, parochial, perscriptive as to be a specific reference or joke. Like telling someone who's going to come over and work on a car to bring their 10mm wrench because they lost one before.

Comment: The author may well have done. If they did, it was very subtle and was not the takeaway that I got. You could always ask him directly @Stephenturbek https://twitter.com/Stephenturbek

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I liked the article, it is packed with information. I think this is a good place to ask, too. Judging by the upvote someone else did also.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailing_list

> A mailing list is a collection of names and addresses used by an
> individual or an organization to send material to multiple recipients.
> The term is often extended to include the people subscribed to such a
> list, so the group of subscribers is referred to as "the mailing
> list", or simply "the list".
>
> At least two types of mailing lists can be defined:
>
> An announcement list is closer to the original sense, where a "mailing list" of people
> was used as a recipient for newsletters, periodicals or advertising.
> The second type allows members to post their own items which are broadcast to all
> of the other mailing list members. This second category is usually
> known as a discussion list.

http://www.python.org/community/lists/ has a few examples of mailing lists.